# What happens when user does not respond to Push Notification?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Lets assume a user receives a notification.  The user did not respond to notification.  what happens? will it automatically get closed? if yes, what is the duration for the expiry of notification on the device? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notification will not automatically get closed, but if another one comes in—be it a text message, a voicemail, or even a notification from another app—then your notification will effectively vanish. If the notification payload includes a badge number for your app, then that will get updated; aside from that, though, once another notification supersedes it, yours is gone.

Answer (score 0):

To your app the behaviour will be the same as if he tapped the close button.

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't respond, your app will never know. The push message will remain on the screen until the phone is unlocked or some other message is received (SMS or other push notification)